# Explanation of Set Identity $(E_1 E_2 E_3)^c = E_1 \cup (E_1 E_2^c) \cup (E_1 E_2 E_3^c)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I ran across the following set identity in a probability problem: 
$$(E_1 E_2 E_3)^c = E_1 \cup (E_1 E_2^c) \cup (E_1 E_2 E_3^c)$$ and can't make heads or tails of it. I tried applying De Morgan's law as follows:
$$ (E_1 E_2 E_3)^c = E_1^c  \cup E_2^c \cup E_3^c$$
but don't see how this helps. I am not necessarily looking for a proof of the identity, but rather a way to understand heuristically why it is true, although a proof would probably help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consequcne of your identity is
$$(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3)^c \subseteq E_1;$$
do you see a problem?

Comment: Yes, I see the contradiction here. Thank you, the solution I was looking at came from a less than completely reputable source and I won't be as trusting the next time.